# Redis caching Map<Integer, String>

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis, jsonserializer

I an using redis cache and faced the problem: map with integer key is serialized as String like this:

```
 "1":"AAAA","2":"BBB","3":"CCC"
```

This is how my config looks like:

```
@Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration myCacheConfiguration()
    {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ZERO)
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair
                        .fromSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Map.class)));
    }

  @Bean
    public CacheManager myCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory)
    {
        return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(myCacheConfiguration())
                .transactionAware()
                .build();
    }
```

I tried to pass GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer to serializeValuesWith(), but is doesn't work.
Is there any way to serialize\deserialize Integer keys of map as number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is easily solved by adding overriding of method JavaType getJavaType(Class clazz) in Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.
Documentation says:

```
/**
     * Returns the Jackson {@link JavaType} for the specific class.
     * <p>
     * Default implementation returns {@link TypeFactory#constructType(java.lang.reflect.Type)}, but this can be
     * overridden in subclasses, to allow for custom generic collection handling. For instance:
     *
     * <pre class="code">
     * protected JavaType getJavaType(Class&lt;?&gt; clazz) {
     *  if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
     *      return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, MyBean.class);
     *  } else {
     *      return super.getJavaType(clazz);
     *  }
     * }
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param clazz the class to return the java type for
     * @return the java type
     */
    protected JavaType getJavaType(Class<?> clazz) {
        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(clazz);
    }
```

So, I just overriding this method like this:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer
{
    public JurisdictionsSerializer(Class type)
    {
        super(type);
    }


    @Override
    protected JavaType getJavaType(Class clazz)
    {
        return TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                .constructMapType(Map.class, Integer.class, String.class);
    }
}
```

And then add this serializer to redis configuration like this:

```
@Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration myCacheConfiguration()
    {
        return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                .entryTtl(Duration.ZERO)
                .disableCachingNullValues()
                .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair
                        .fromSerializer(new CustomSerializer(Map.class)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer` and `GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer` both allow to use custom `ObjectMapper`.

No familiar with Redis, but seems that's designed way for custom serialization according to the [doc](http://Setting%20a%20custom-configured%20ObjectMapper%20is%20one%20way%20to%20take%20further%20control%20of%20the%20JSON%20serialization%20process.%20For%20example,%20an%20extended%20SerializerFactory%20can%20be%20configured%20that%20provides%20custom%20serializers%20for%20specific%20types.%20The%20other%20option%20for%20refining%20the%20serialization%20process%20is%20to%20use%20Jackson's%20provided%20annotations%20on%20the%20types%20to%20be%20serialized,%20in%20which%20case%20a%20custom-configured%20ObjectMapper%20is%20unnecessary.):

> Setting a custom-configured `ObjectMapper` is one way to take further
>   control of the JSON serialization process. For example, an extended
>   `SerializerFactory` can be configured that provides custom serializers
>   for specific types. The other option for refining the serialization
>   process is to use Jackson's provided annotations on the types to be
>   serialized, in which case a custom-configured ObjectMapper is
>   unnecessary.